# how to separate string from number into different positions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe below, but the column "Column_2" have str and date together.
How to separate that?

```
data = {'Column_1': ["foo","bar","foo","foo","bar"],
    'Column_2': ["PAID_202109_ASD","DENIED_202109_ASD", "202108_APPROVED_DSA", 
                 "AUTHORIZED_202107_qtd_DSA","202107_AUTHORIZED_ASD"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
```

[image]

expected result:

```
>>> df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `extract` and `replace`:

```
df["Data"] = df["Column_2"].str.extract("(\d+)")
df["Str"] = df['Column_2'].str.replace("(\d_)+"," ", regex=True).str.strip()

>>> df
 Column_1                   Column_2    Data                 Str
0      foo            PAID_202109_ASD  202109            PAID ASD
1      bar          DENIED_202109_ASD  202109          DENIED ASD
2      foo        202108_APPROVED_DSA  202108        APPROVED DSA
3      foo  AUTHORIZED_202107_qtd_DSA  202107  AUTHORIZED qtd DSA
4      bar      202107_AUTHORIZED_ASD  202107      AUTHORIZED ASD
```

Comment: I believe the second can be simplified to `df['Column_2'].str.replace(r'[\d_]+',' ')`, which replaces all the substrings containing numbers or underscores by a single whitespace, separating, therefore, the alphabetic substrings.

Comment: @HarryPlotter - That might then need a `strip()` for cases when the date is at the beginning or end of the column :). I thought of that too ;)

Comment: good observation ;)

Comment: @HarryPlotter - it does however look more readable even with the `strip` though. Edited! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First explode your `Column_2` then create your 2 columns:

```
out = df['Column_2'].str.split('_').explode()
mask = out.str.isdigit()  # or .str.fullmatch('\d{6}')
df['Data'] = out[mask]
df['Str'] = out[~mask].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
print(df)

# Output:
  Column_1                   Column_2    Data                 Str
0      foo            PAID_202109_ASD  202109            PAID ASD
1      bar          DENIED_202109_ASD  202109          DENIED ASD
2      foo        202108_APPROVED_DSA  202108        APPROVED DSA
3      foo  AUTHORIZED_202107_qtd_DSA  202107  AUTHORIZED qtd DSA
4      bar      202107_AUTHORIZED_ASD  202107      AUTHORIZED ASD
```

I used `str.isdigit()` to determine if the row is a number or not. You can also use something like `str.fullmatch('\d{6}')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Str"] =df['Column_2'].str.replace('[\_]',' ', regex=True).str.replace('\d+\s+','', regex=True)#First replace - with nothing and all digits followed by space with nothing
df["data"] =df['Column_2'].str.replace('[^\d]',' ', regex=True).str.strip()#Replace everything except digit



 Column_1                   Column_2                 Str    data
0      foo            PAID_202109_ASD            PAID ASD  202109
1      bar          DENIED_202109_ASD          DENIED ASD  202109
2      foo        202108_APPROVED_DSA        APPROVED DSA  202108
3      foo  AUTHORIZED_202107_qtd_DSA  AUTHORIZED qtd DSA  202107
4      bar      202107_AUTHORIZED_ASD      AUTHORIZED ASD  202107
```